# Problem with math text and decorations [tikz]

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

I want to write some math text arround a circle, it works fine for math formulas but when I tried to write `\varSigma` and  `\varPi` from `amsmath` package, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text along path, text={$\varSigma \varPi MAX$}}]
\path [decorate]
(0,0) .. controls (0,6) and (9,6) .. (9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to put each symbol into brackets, like: `{$\varSigma$} {$\varPi$} {$MAX$}`

Comment: `{$\varSigma$}{$\varPi$}{$MAX$}{}` works fine. add your comment as an answer please and i'll give you the points because you solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each math symbol needs to be a in a separated couple of brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text along path, text={{$\varSigma$} {$\varPi$} {$MAX$}}}]
\path [decorate]
(0,0) .. controls (0,6) and (9,6) .. (9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you need to put something (like a `{}`)after the couple of brackets where the math env is: `{$\varSigma \varPi MAX$}{}`